# Hibernate Entity Mapping - Main Entity and member extend a another base

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, entity, one-to-many

I am not sure if this is feasible.

I have an entity `User` mapped to `USERS` table,  which extends a class `Base`.
So `Base` class maps some of the columns from `USERS` table.

There is another entity with name `UserAddress` mapped to `USER_ADDR` table.
`UserAddress` also extends `Base` since it maps some columns from `USER_ADDR` table.

Here is the pseudo code.

```
@Entity
public class User extends Base {

  private String xyz;    

  @OneToMany
  Set<UserAddress> addresses;
  ...
  ...
}

@Entity
public class UserAddress extends Base {

  private String xyz;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn (name= 'xyz', insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private User updatedUser;

}

@MappedSuperClass
public class Base {
   // ...some common columns that exist in both User and UserAddress
}
```

So

- `User` and `UserAddress` extend `Base`
- `User` has `UserAddress` as Member variable.
- `UserAddress` has a member variable that refers to `User`

Is this feasible?

Comment: Is UserAddress.updatedUser always in the User.addresses list?

Comment: Yes, it is. Does it help?